# java web start JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have an application that starts a Swing gui using java web start.  The user has 4 versions of java 1.6 installed (1.6.0.3, 1.6.0.5, 1.6.0.7. 1.6.0.11)

Webstart is selecting java version 1.6.0.11 but JAVA_HOME is set to java version 1.6.0.3.  Could this cause any potential problems for webstart?

- rich

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this thread](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5282583), it is mentioned a Java Web Start application check the version of an available JRE in this path:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\[User]\Application Data\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties
(for Windows XP)

C:\Users\[User]\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties
(for Windows Vista)
```

In it, lines like:

```
deployment.javaws.jre.0.path=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\javaw.exe
deployment.javaws.jre.0.product=1.6.0_11
```

are found.

I believe the JWS will start with those settings, not the ones from a `JAVA_HOME` variable, which should not be a problem.

As [detailed here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/properties.html),

> The **`deployment.properties`** file is used for storing and retrieving deployment configuration properties in the Java Control Panel. They are **also used for customizing runtime behavior for both Java Plug-in and Java Web Start**.
>
> There is always a User-Level `deployment.properties` file. Its location, which is non-configurable, is described below. There may also be an (optional) System-Level `deployment.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look inside the jave web start script.  They might have their own JRE or JDK path inside it.  The user might be even using a version that is not listed on the list above.  This is usually done to easy installation on the end-user.

Hope you find the solution.